# Multiple property Full-Text Search with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've this `C#` code to query my `MongoDB` collection:

```
var query = myCollection.FindAll().AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
query = query.Where(
    x => x.User.FullName.IndexOf(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productName))
query = query.Where(
    x => x.Product.ProductName.IndexOf(productName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

query = query.Take(pageSize).Skip(pageSize*(pageNumber-1));

var itemCount=query.Count();
var result = query.ToList();
```

Due to low performance now I want to use a full-text search. I created `text` index for `User.FullName` and `Product.ProductName` and I started to write code like this:

```
var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
        {
            { "text", myCollection.Name },
            { "search", username }
        };
var commandResult = _database.RunCommand(textSearchCommand);
var result = commandResult.Response;
```

Now I'm stuck; How to specify the property name in the above syntax example? Is this the right way to do that?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean here. What does your actual document look like and which fields are actually indexed? You can specify more than one field in a full text index. Even if you can only have one per collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text index points to the document as a whole, not to the individual field where the match occurs. That means a text-search is always performed on all fields which are part of the text-index. You can not selectively only search for matches in one field.

But what you can do is further filter the result-set of the [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text)-operator with additional operators. You could, for example, use an additional [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)-operator to check if the string you searched for occurs in the field where you want it to be.

Comment: I think I'm miss something here! Think about this very common and simple example: a huge collection (200.000) of user object with name and city and a simple search form where I can type partial name and partial city name... Have I to use RegHex without index? Now a similar query with only 80.000 docs takes 4 seconds!

Comment: @danyolgiax MongoDB text indexes do not work with partial words. They can only search for full words in various grammatical permutations depending on the language-settings. When you want to search for incomplete words, you have to use $regex. But note that regular expressions can benefit from indexes when they begin with a begin-of-string anchor `^`. So when the user starts typing "New" you can search for `{city: { $regex : "^New" }}` and find "New York", "New Orleans" and "Newcastle" via an index on `city`.

Comment: Saved me with this last comment! Thx!